# How do I wire up this relay?

Tags: relay, wiring, basic

I'm making [this circuit](http://www.simprojects.nl/toggle_to_momentary.htm):

[image]

I've bought an Omron G5LA-1 non-latching SPDT relay. It looks like this (from [the datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0b76/0900766b80b76b3c.pdf)):

[image]

I'm struggling to figure out how I wire this up though. I believe I need to ignore a pin, but I'm not sure which. I also don't know what gets wired to which pin.

I have the circuit wired up with the power, tumbler switch, and capacitor so far.

The keyboard just looks something like this, where 2 of the 26 contacts would be connected:

[image]

Any guidance with figuring out what goes to which pin is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore pin 4, that's the normally closed contact. It's that simple. Note that the diagram is looking at the *bottom* of the part, not from the top through it.

1 and 3 are the switch that closes when the coil is energized, it doesn't matter which is which, and they go to the keyboard.

2 and 5 are the coil.. again it doesn't matter which is which.

Test it out before hooking it up to the keyboard- you should hear the relay clacking as it operates with the "tumbler switch".

When you do hook it up, keep the connections neat, shorts kill parts.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply Spehro! It works perfectly, thanks a lot! :)